# Accessing multiple dimension array with a pointer to a struct

Tags: c

basically I have 2d array in a struct that I access through a pointer and i can't figure out how to access `matrix[i][j]` in my `if` statement

```
struct Matrix{
    unsigned int matrix_size;
    int matrix [MAX_MATRIX][MAX_MATRIX];
};


short is_matrix_ok(const struct Matrix*n){
    for(int i=0;i<n-matrix_size;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n->matrix_size;j++){
          if(n->(matrix+i)[j] ?????)
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `n->matrix[i][j]`.

`matrix` is a member of the structure. `matrix+i` is not, so you cannot use `n->(matrix+i)`. You must first get the member of the structure, `n->matrix`, and then you can apply operations to that, like `n->matrix[i]`, which is equivalent to `(n->matrix)[i]`, and then you can apply the next subscript, `n->matrix[i][j]`.

If you want to access it using pointers rather than subscripts, then it would be `n->matrix + i` to calculate a pointer to subarray `i`. Then `*(n->matrix + i)` is that subarray. As an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so `*(n->matrix + i) + j` calculates a pointer to element `j` of subarray `i`. Finally, `*(*(n->matrix + i) + j)` is element `j` of subarray `i`.

Never use that pointer expression in normal code without good reason. Use the easier-to-read `n->matrix[i][j]`.

Answer (score -2):

Try the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 2

struct Matrix{
    int matrix[ROWS][COLS];
};

short read_matrix(struct Matrix *M){
    int tmp = -100;
    for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<COLS;j++){
            scanf("%d\n", &tmp);
            M->matrix[i][j] = tmp;
            //printf("tmp is %d\n", tmp);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}

short is_matrix_ok(const struct Matrix *M){
    for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<COLS;j++){
            printf("n[%d][%d] = %d\n",i,j,M->matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}

int main(){
    struct Matrix Mat;
    read_matrix(&Mat);
    is_matrix_ok(&Mat);
    return(0);
}
```

If you input 1 to 6, output is as follows:

```
n[0][0] = 1
n[0][1] = 2
n[1][0] = 3
n[1][1] = 4
n[2][0] = 5
n[2][1] = 6
```

Comment: For future reference, this answer was discussed on Meta: [Why am I receiving downvotes when little has changed in my answering style?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407867/12892553)